# ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QTGUI

Tags: python, cygwin, pyqt4

I have installed the PyQt4 library and have the following at the start of the code

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
......
```

This runs perfectly well when I run the code from the windows Python Gui (IDLE).
However, when I tried to run the code from Cygwin, I get the below error:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QTGUI
```

Can I know what is wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cygwin and Windows Python installations are completely separate and incompatible.  In order to use `PyQt4` with Cygwin's Python, you will need to the `python-pyqt4` package.